# Case select another column AS400 query

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I have simple query which is not working:

```
SELECT BATCH_0002.CREATOR, BATCH_0002.GLEXR,
case when BATCH_0002.GLIVD >'0' THEN BATCH_0002.GLIVD ELSE BATCH_0002.date end 
as tarih FROM BATCH_0002
```

Error is:

> ERROR: [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0581 -  The
>   results in a CASE expression are not compatible. Error Code: 
>   -581

but when I change column name to something different than `GLIVD`, it is working.

```
SELECT BATCH_0002.CREATOR, BATCH_0002.GLEXR,
case when BATCH_0002.GLIVD >'0' THEN BATCH_0002.GLEXR ELSE BATCH_0002.date end 
as tarih FROM BATCH_0002
```

Is there something wrong with my case statement?

Comment: Can you post the table definition for `BATCH_0002` ?

Comment: which  data types are the columns  GLIVD and GLEXR ?

Answer (score 0):

In Case statement result datatype should be same. Here Using int and date as result in case that's why error showing for incompatible data

you should cast one datatype to another

```
SELECT BATCH_0002.CREATOR, BATCH_0002.GLEXR, case when BATCH_0002.GLIVD >'0' THEN cast(BATCH_0002.GLIVD as char) ELSE cast(BATCH_0002.date as char) end as tarih FROM BATCH_0002
```

Comment: thank you but this is working ;        case when BATCH_0002.GLIVD >0 THEN BATCH_0002.GLEXR ELSE BATCH_0002.date end as tarih FROM BATCH_0002 GLIVD is "numeric" GLEXTR is "char(30)" DATE is "date"

Comment: date can be cast as char but not in numeric value

Comment: SELECT BATCH_0002.CREATOR, BATCH_0002.GLEXR,
case when BATCH_0002.GLIVD >'0' THEN cast(BATCH_0002.GLIVD as char) ELSE BATCH_0002.date end 
as tarih FROM BATCH_0002

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all answers regarding data types. worked on this information and now solved, this works very well:

```
    SELECT BATCH_0002.CREATOR, BATCH_0002.GLEXR, 
    case when BATCH_0002.GLIVD >'0' THEN 
    DATE(CHAR(1900000 + BATCH_0002.GLIVD)) 
    ELSE BATCH_0002.date end as tarih FROM BATCH_0002
```